# center the component in borderlayout - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I used borderLayout center but it is only centering the component with respect to the screenwidth but not screen height. So I used BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER. It centers the component in the middle of the form but I have animation that should take whole screen size but it is only taking component size.

menu Animation:

```
private void menuAnimation(Container c) {
    int w = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
    int h = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();
    int[] positionX = {-100, w / 2, w + 100, w + 100, w + 100, w / 2, -100, -100};
    int[] positionY = {-100, -100, -100, h / 2, h + 100, h + 100, h + 100, h / 2};
    for (int iter = 0; iter < c.getComponentCount(); iter++) {
        Component cmp = c.getComponentAt(iter);
        cmp.setY(positionY[iter % positionY.length]);
        cmp.setX(positionX[iter % positionX.length]);
    }
}
```

code:

```
    //f.setLayout(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));

    Container menuContainerGroup = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    f.add(menuContainerGroup);

    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(3, 3);
    Container menuContainer = new Container(tl);

    menuContainerGroup.add(menuContainer);

    Image round = theme.getImage("loginBg.png").scaledWidth(imgWidth / 3 - 10);

    Label menuIcon = new Label();
    menuIcon.setUIID("menuButton");

    Button menuIcon1 = new Button(round);
    menuIcon1.setUIID("menuButton");
    menuIcon1.addActionListener((e) -> {
        menuAnimation(menuContainer);
        menuContainer.animateUnlayoutAndWait(600, 20);
        showForm("", null);

    });

    Label menuIcon2 = new Label();
    menuIcon2.setUIID("menuButton");

    Button menuIcon3 = new Button(round);
    menuIcon3.setUIID("menuButton");
    menuIcon3.addActionListener((e) -> {
        menuAnimation(menuContainer);
        menuContainer.animateUnlayoutAndWait(600, 20);
        showForm("", null);
    });

    Button menuIcon4 = new Button("Sign Out");
    menuIcon4.setUIID("menuButton");
    menuIcon4.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xff7800);
    menuIcon4.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
    menuIcon4.addActionListener((e) -> {
        menuAnimation(menuContainer);
        menuContainer.animateUnlayoutAndWait(600, 20);
        showForm("", null);
    });

    Button menuIcon5 = new Button(round);
    menuIcon5.setUIID("menuButton");
    menuIcon5.addActionListener((e) -> {
        menuAnimation(menuContainer);
        menuContainer.animateUnlayoutAndWait(600, 20);
        showForm("", null);
    });

    Label menuIcon6 = new Label();
    menuIcon6.setUIID("menuButton");

    Button menuIcon7 = new Button(round);
    menuIcon7.setUIID("menuButton");
    menuIcon7.addActionListener((e) -> {
        menuAnimation(menuContainer);
        menuContainer.animateUnlayoutAndWait(600, 20);
        showForm("", null);
    });

    Label menuIcon8 = new Label();
    menuIcon8.setUIID("menuButton");

    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon1);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon2);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon3);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon4);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon5);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon6);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon7);
    menuContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33), menuIcon8);
    f.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the component is contained within a Container that is within the border layout position. So when you animate it you are rendering it outside of the bounds of its parent container which clip it into place.

A possible solution might be to set the constraint for the center layout after the fact and then use `animateLayoutHierarchy` which will animate both the constraint effect and the position of the element.

Comment: I do not understand the solution part, sorry

Comment: By not using the center constraint the UI will expand over the entire screen and clipping will work correctly. When you apply the new layout constraint and then call animateLayoutHierarchy it will animate the entire hierarchy instead of the specific component and will slowly shrink down the parent container so the animation should be visible.

Comment: I have removed center constraint. But still the animation is within the component only. Also I need to place the entire component groups in the center of the screen too. Can you please correct my code in your answer please.

Comment: I can't correct the code because it's non-trivial and has external dependencies.  I suggest turning on slow motion mode in the simulator and setting a line border for every container within the hierarchy to see where the container is clipping the UI. This will allow you to see which container you need to fix

Comment: thanks it helped. I added the padding to the container that give it required dimension but doing it I have to code for orientation differently and so on. Is there a way so that I can center the component ( with respect to width and height) in a particular dimension? I tried constraint and behavior in borderlayout , it clip the excess area.

Comment: The approach you took should work the main problem is the nesting within the animated containers.